# Random special characters in insert

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following Code in C# ( Sql server (LocalDB)\v11.0)
If Definition property has no special character , the Insert executed. but
some times it has an unknown special character in it , and i recive the Error.

```
 for()
  {
  if(){
  DB.Docommand("INSERT INTO Test5(P_Def) VALUES('"+ pro.Definition + "')");
      }
  }
```

in database the data type is nvarchar(Max)
but i receive the following error:

incorrect syntax near .....

I want to insert my property with special characters.
What can id do?
Thanks

Comment: The short answer is change `VALUES('"+` to `VALUES(N'"+`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameterize your insert. In addition to gaining an ability to insert strings with any characters that are valid inside `nvarchar`, you will also fix a major security problem by avoiding a potential [sql injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14376473/335858):

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test5(P_Def) VALUES(@Def)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Def", pro.Definition);
```